# Tfs 2013 Api: capacity and days off

Tags: api, tfs

I develop small project using tfs API. I have no problems with working with workItems,projects or teams but i'm wondering if is possible to get capacity and days off for specific team and specific iteration (within one project). It is possible to achive in TFS 2013 (or maybe in TFS 2015)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/work/capacity) REST Api of TFS2015

Comment: So far i used approach described here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2012/05/21/tfs-api-part-45-vs11-modify-teams-and-team-members/ and want to be consistent-of course if it's possible.

Comment: The TFS2013 Api doesn't have the possibility to get the team's capacity (unless you want to interrogate the operational database which is not recommended/supported).

Comment: you may vote this uservoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7159817-add-api-support-for-querying-iteration-dates-user